# Copy drop files from build to remote machine

Tags: release-management, build-agent

I need to create release definition in VSTS. I had been created build definition that build solution from master and drops all files needed on the drop folder when a commit in master is done.

I want to create release definition that deploys a given build into remote machine. I had tried two ways, [Copy files task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC0wb.png) and PowerShell script task to copy the drop files to the remote machine. But both are the same error with
[fail to connect to the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAlU.jpg).

But if I run the PowerShell script in my local machine, it can copy the files to that server.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows Machine File Copy task. Error 53 is pretty generic, but in general it means one of these things:

1. File/print sharing isn't enabled on the target machine
2. The SMB port (445) is being blocked by the Windows firewall or a corporate firewall